# Would the Doppeler effect be incorrect to use as evidence to support an expanding universe?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, astronomy, redshift

In our science class we have a question to answer, which is 'explain how redshift supports the idea of an expanding universe'.

I am not sure how to answer this question, as I know that there are 'different types' of redshifts. The one we (my class) were focusing on for this topic was the Doppeler effect. We were told that the galaxies were moving away from us, so that causes the light to shift. I have explained it like this in the past and have gotten it correct, however, I also know that on a scale so large, that space itself expansing is causing the redshift. So I am not sure how I should answer this question because I feel like the teacher is asking us to explain the doppeler effect, not cosmological redshift. So if I explain it using the Doppeler effect example, would the answer generally be incorrect because it is cosmological redshift that supports an expanding universe?

Comment: It doesn't matter. In the Milne model, space does not expand, so the redshift is Doppler. In the "official" Friedmann model, space does expand, so the redshift is cosmological. Either way, the redshift proves the expansion of the universe.

Comment: @safesphere, if "space does not expand" in the Milne model, then how in that model does "redshift prove the expansion of the universe" - where can the expansion occur, other than in space? Or is the implication that the concept of "the universe" in this context encompasses only non-empty space, and the contents of the universe are thus spilling out into a larger area of previously empty space? In other words, "space" in the Milne model extends beyond the limits of the universe? If so, redshift does not prove "expansion" according to any particular sense in which the word is used.

Comment: @Steve In the Milne model, the expansion of the universe can be viewed as an explosion of matter into an infinite static space. However, this model is also compliant with the FLRW cosmology as a special case. In this view, the universe in this model expands as an expansion of space. Both views are equivalent thus confirming that the Doppler redshift is equivalent to the cosmological redshift.

Comment: @safesphere, ah. I would only say then that when two models have an inconsistent definition of expansion, and the evidence is consistent with both, neither can be said to be "proved".

Comment: @Steve The definition of the expansion of the universe is consistent in all models. It is simply the fact that galaxies are receding from each other. Whether they are receding by flying apart in a static space or by being carried away by an expanding space depends on the model and its interpretation, but doesn't change the definition of the expansion of the universe. You seem to think of the expansion of the universe as of the expansion of space. However these are different concepts. The latter is one of possible reasons of the former.

Comment: @safesphere, the concept of expansion in one of these models does not seem synonymous with the concept of expansion in the other - which is what distinguishes them as separate models. Neither model is proven - for if one were, then all others would be disproved. How then does the proof of expansion arise? It cannot be arising from these models, because neither is yet proven. And the redshift itself cannot be the proof as you say - it is the unexplained cause of the redshift, in terms of any other physics, which these unproven models seek to explain.

Comment: I should add further. Even if we accept that these models, which each employ some expansionary concept, are the only explanatory models currently available, that does not itself imply that one member of this class of models must be correct - unless all other kinds of model have already been positively ruled out. Otherwise, when the first of these models was conceived and before the second, we would have jumped to the conclusion that the first was correct (because it was, at that time, the only model available).

Comment: @Steve The expansion of the universe is an experimental fact discovered by Edwin Hubble who correlated the redshift of remote galaxies to their velocities measured in a different way. Now this is called the Hubble Law, which is the experimental law that has nothing to do with any cosmological model. What these models attempt to explain is the mechanism behind the expansion of the universe, but the expansion itself is an experimental fact. Also, interestingly, there is no direct experimental evidence yet that space is expanding or that the observable universe is smaller than the whole universe.

Comment: @safesphere, there are indeed a constellation of theories around expansion. I would say they all currently fall short of *proof*. They are more akin to speculation and provisional conclusions, and generally raise more questions than they answer (which is not to denigrate the attempt to grapple with the problem). And that is not to contradict the fact that we do observe redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Cosmological and Doppler redshifts are equivalent.

We usually use the "Cosmic expansion stretches light wavelengths" explanation, because it is intuitive, and a completely valid explanation.

However, we could equally well see cosmological redshift as the accumulated Doppler redshifts between the local rest frames of every set of neighboring points in the Universe.

As a photon travels through expanding space, it travels through a series of spatial points, which each has their own frame of being "at rest", slightly different from that of the neighboring points. As the photon travels, this difference builds up, and redshift accumulates.

If I am at point A, and a photon is emitted at point B some cosmological distance from me, an observer at rest at an intermediate point C will see the light from point B as less redshifted than I do at point A. But from my point of view, I might as well say -- and equally true -- that tpoint C is also moving relative to me, and that the difference in perceived redshifts is due to their velocity, not because anybody is stretching their light waves.

Of course, the danger of using the simple Doppler Shift framework of explanation is that it may lead to wrong conclusions like e.g. the widespread misconception that the redshift approaces infinity as the recession velocity approaches $c$, that either galaxies can never recede form us faster than light (they can) or that we can never see galaxies receding faster than light (we can). These are usually based on misunderstandings about how Relaytivity works (which is not so strange, it can be quite difficult to understand and I certainly drew all these wrong conclusions myself until I was taught that they were wrong).

Comment: *"As a photon travels through expanding space..."* Doesn't that beg the very question asked? The OP asserts that the observed redshift is consistent with at least two explanations: (a) the recessing of the source; and (b) the expansion of the space between the source and observer. These would seem to be subtly but fundamentally different explanations (one attributes movement to the source, the other attributes an expansionary behaviour to the empty space itself), and the OP doesn't seem sure that the redshift supports either explanation against the other.

Comment: "*the danger of using the simple Doppler Shift framework of explanation is that it may lead to wrong conclusions like e.g. the widespread misconception that the redshift approaces infinity as the recession velocity approaches* $c$" - I think by "wrong" you actually mean "non compliant with the official model". These conclusions are not necessarily wrong in other models. For example, if I interpret the Milne model as an explosion in the infinite Minkowski space, then these conclusions would be correct and not "misconceptions", would they not?